# Monitoring whether a file has been changed on a remote web server

Tags: linux, windows, apache-2.2

What's the best method for monitoring whether a file has been changed on a remote web servers given the following preconditions?

- Servers are running different operating system but most are some flavor of Linux, a couple are running Windows Server.
- SSH access isn't available on all servers.
- The check is primarily to test that php templates used to generate pages, haven't been corrupted. The template doesn't change in size so the checksum of the file is always the same specifically replaced by an administrator.

So far I've only come up with the option of placing a file specifically on each server and then polling each of those files to retrieve diagnostic data. I have some concerns however about whether those file may themselves be compromised if they are in a public facing directory to require polling by an external source.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to tripwire, but OSSEC will watch for file modifications as well: http://www.ossec.net (this'll require a lightweight agent to be installed on the servers in question).

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you describe is exactly the behavior of services like https://monitorwebsitefilechanges.cloud

You load on your site a simple php agent that is periodically interrogated to obtain a snapshot of the files on your web space (file names, their size and last modified date). This data is then compared with the previous snapshot and you get notified when files are added, deleted or modified.

I prefer this type of service compared to [tripwire](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/)  because they do not require any installation and also work on inexpensive hosting without SSH access and without cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use monit tool to achive that. Below is the URL worth to give a try.

http://mmonit.com/monit/

Answer (score 0):

I believe [tripwire](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/) will do what you want. It can monitor a system for changes to files and send email alerts if the files change.

Answer (score 0):

You may use nagios for that - basically it is easy to write Your own plugin to fire diff and check if there any differences against predefined, and write protected sample. Probably it is much more flexible than tripwire which basically works on checksum based tests, whilst nagios may works on what You need. Here is an example: http://blog.gnucom.cc/2010/check-file-for-changes-with-nagios/

Answer (score 0):

in linux systems you can user innotify-tools. This tool is working on kernel level and can handle events like - create/delete/modified/ and others on files and directories.